# Register-ObjectEvent: MaxTriggerCount parameter, what does it do?

Tags: powershell

I am challenged to find useful documents on this parameter.

It appears, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-7.2), that it means the event will trigger n times and then auto-unregister, *but the docs are far from clear*.

Is my interpretation warm?

And if warm, how can I use this to prevent recursion?

IOW, I would like to set it to 1, so my event fires, but is not retriggered by events my action code takes. Then I would register the event again at the end of my code.

Can an event be registered from within the action block of that very event?

Comment: Re registering again from inside an `-Action` script block: haven't tried it, but _un_-registering can cause a hang -see [GitHub issue #16154](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16154).